# Why only call a private function in a public function?

Tags: python, function, private-methods, python-chess

I was wandering in the source code of the fabulous [python-chess](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-chess) library when I saw the following code:

```
def _reset_board(self):
    # code...

def reset_board(self):
    self._reset_board()
```

The `reset_board()` function only does one thing, call its private counterpart. Is there a reason behind this? Wouldn't putting the code directly in the private function be faster due to python not have to resolve the name `_reset_board()`?

Comment: I'll say it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Most of the time dunder name means don't mess with this code if you don't know exactly what you are doing. so my guess is, if there's someone who wants to hook into `reset_board()` to do something before or after the `reset_board()` they can in a spot that is relevantly clean, without messing with the actual function

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri And what are the arguments supporting it? Because I cannot seem to be able to think of any.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis argument supporting what? That it is opinion based?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Opinion based implies that are people who find such a construct useful and other who don't. The latter group I understand; I find it unnecessary too. What are the arguments of the people supporting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_reset_board` exists so it can be called from both [`reset_board`](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/v0.22.1/chess/__init__.py#L528) and [`__init__`](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/v0.22.1/chess/__init__.py#L509). `__init__` can't call `self.reset_board`, because that method is overridden in subclasses, and `__init__` wants to call the specific `_reset_board` implementation from its own class. (Subclass `reset_board` implementations may depend on initialization that hasn't happened yet, among other problems.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, here this `_reset_board` is not necessary. The author probably did some wrapping/cleaning in the `reset_board` method before, removed it, and didn't take the time to remove the `_reset_board`. Or maybe he plans to add some wrapping/cleaning in there in the future.

Some project also may generate Documentation automatically based on the code, and may skip functions/method that start with a `_`, and he may not want to publish any documentation for this function, but being open source, it's probably not the real reason.